# Why does google play music conceal music files from the user on an android but not on a desktop computer?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-music

It seems inconsistent to me. I can do anything I want with files I bought from the play store as long as I'm on my computer. What's the point of restricting access on phones?

Answer (score 0):

Google Music tries its best to hide the music files everywhere, but some cases (like connecting your phone to a computer) cannot be prevented. If you have rooted your phone you actually can access the files using the right tools.

It's part of fighting piracy: Google can't prevent piracy but they can make it as hard and inconvenient as possible so users will pay for their music.

Comment: Yeah but take phones out of the picture(I know this is an android forum). I can use a Mac to buy play store music. The files are right where I keep all my music on my mac. I was able to attach a google-purchased song to an email. So why different rules for different devices? Just wondering if anyone thinks that makes sense.

Comment: I think it's because Google is trying to push its music on de mand ("Spotify") service. If you can access the downloaded files, you can play all your favourite songs in the trial and keep the high quality audio files. It might also be a attempt at forcing users to use their music app, because you're less likely to switch to a competitor if it's hard to play your music in another app.